# Как на bitbucket.org добавить ключ ssh, чтобы по нему можно было записывать данные в репозиторий

Tags: bitbucket

Access keys
Use access keys to gain read-only access to this repository. Learn more about using SSH keys.

Как добавить write доступ по ключу ?

Answer (score 0):

В настройках аккаунта на сайте ищешь пункт ssh-ключи. 
Если вдруг не сможешь понять как зайти в настройки попробуй сгенерировать ссылку: [https://bitbucket.org/account/user/ТВОЙ_ЛОГИН/ssh-keys/](https://bitbucket.org/account/user/%D0%A2%D0%92%D0%9E%D0%99_%D0%9B%D0%9E%D0%93%D0%98%D0%9D/ssh-keys/)

Ключ генерировать проще все на мой взгляд через утилиту GitExtensions.

`Tools - Putty - Generate or import`
Жмешь кнопку генерировать и водишь мышкой, после сохраняешь свой приватный ключи, а публичный копирует целиком и добаляешь его на сайт в текстовом виде.

Теперь при каждом коммите GitExtensions  будет подхватывать твой приватный ключ и автоматически авторизоваться.

Comment: ключ у меня есть и я его добавляю, но коммитить в репозитарий нельзя, так как ключ добавляется с правами только на чтение.

Comment: @inzem77 сам ключ никак не ограничивает уровень доступа, который настроен в репозитории. Возможно вы добавили свой ключ в настройках самого проекта. Такой ключ дает только readonly доступ.